# Safecracker submitting form before finished

Tags: safecracker, validation

I have a relatively simple multipage safecracker form where users can upload an image on the first page, approve the image and add a description on the second, then add tags on the third.

All three fields are set as required in channel fields.

However today I noticed that from the moment the user uploads an image and presses 'submit' to proceed to adding the description the entry is already displaying on the website. No required field errors at all.

I'm a bit confused, any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you share some code which can give more idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi-page form will create the entry after the first step. I'd recommend adding status="closed" to the first page's form, and status="open" to the last page's form. This way, when the entry is first created, it won't be visible on the front-end until the last page is completed.